# How to play audio file in back ground mode using swift 2.0?

Tags: swift2

HI i need to play audio file in back ground mode .... i tried some what i know i pasted the below code as

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class PlayingAudio: UIViewController {
    var hitSoundPlayer: AVAudioPlayer? // Global variable

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
               prepareAudios()

    }
    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents()
        self.becomeFirstResponder()
    }
    func prepareAudios() {


                do {
            let hitSound = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Desk-bell-sound", ofType: "wav")!)
            hitSoundPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: hitSound)
            hitSoundPlayer!.prepareToPlay()
            hitSoundPlayer!.play()
        } catch _ {
            hitSoundPlayer = nil
        }
    }
}
```

and i had also switch on the back ground modes in capabilities and set true for audio/air play option now i had hear the sound when the view controller is loaded but i need to hear sound whenever app is in back ground.... what i need to do now ?

Comment: where i need to start that ? i mean in  app delegate or view controller

Comment: thanks for your help ....please see the below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hmm yes i added these lines

```
  do {
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
        print("AVAudioSession Category Playback OK")
        do
        {
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents()
            self.becomeFirstResponder()
            print("AVAudioSession is Active")
        }
        catch let error as NSError
        {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
    catch let error as NSError
    {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
```

in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions and applicationDidEnterBackground
these lines had added `UIApplication.sharedApplication().beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler(nil)
UIApplication.sharedApplication().beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents()`

but i can't hear sound in back ground ?

Comment: you mean add the key with value for back ground mode (under this key "Required background modes")

Comment: yeah thanks  Ashish Kakkad you are right all the things are there in that link.... i found out the mistake what i had  done it ... silly mistake... i played the file which will be play for  3 seconds only that is mistakes....